# Programmatically focus on next entry in Listview (UWP, Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have the following xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewItemPage" ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DataTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <RelativeLayout x:Name="RelativeLayout" >
                    <Label x:Name="DescriptionLabel" Text="{Binding Description}" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=15}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=15}" />
                    <Entry x:Name="ValueEntry" WidthRequest="85" Keyboard="Text" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="19" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource FloatValueConverter}}" Focused="ValueEntry_OnFocused" Unfocused="ValueEntry_OnUnfocused" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=10}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant={StaticResource ConstantMultiPlatform}}" >
                        <Entry.HeightRequest>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="28"></On>
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="42"></On>
                                <On Platform="UWP" Value="32"></On>
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Entry.HeightRequest>
                    </Entry>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And in code, i'm using this method. On Android/IOS it's working well, but on UWP it doesn't work.

```
public async Task GetFocusOnNextEntry()
{
    var focused = (CollectionItemValues)focusedEntry.BindingContext;

    var index = _obserColItemValues.IndexOf(focused);

    var nextEntry = (Entry)ListViewItemPage.TemplatedItems[index + 1].LogicalChildren[0].LogicalChildren[1];
    nextEntry.Focus();
}
```

How do I focus in UWP Xamarin Forms App (Portable) from selected entry to the next entry in Listview?

Comment: I attempt to make custom view cell to reproduce the below issue. It also does not work in my side. And I research some known issue. I found [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60604). It is known issue.

Comment: NicoZhu-MSFT You're right. It's a know issue.

Comment: Maybe a workaround?